# Foundation 6 - Is there a way to hide one navigation on desktop but show it on mobile?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 6 and was wondering if it was possible to display one menu on desktop, but when switched to mobile , I can display a new menu in drilldown and hide the desktop menu?

Comment: Are you sure the question isn't answered when Googling `Foundation 6 - Is there a way to hide one navigation on desktop but show it on mobile?`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, it's under the visibility section in the foundation docs.

Answer (score 0):

To display menu on Large desktop screen, something like ...

```css
<div class="navbar-menu show-for-large large-9 xlarge-10 columns">
  <nav class="dtop-menu">
    <p>Insert code for decktop menu here</p> 
  </nav>
 </div>
```

And to display Hamburger Icon that opens Mobile Menu on Small and Medium size screens, something like ...

```css
<div class="navbar-icon menu-toggle show-for-small hide-for-large small-2 medium-2 text-right">
  <p>Insert code to display Hamburger Icon that opens Mobile Menu here</p>
</div>
```